# How to bind all the subdomains to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: 11.10, dns

I have a domain `test.dev` bound to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`. How can I bind all the subdomains, e.g. `any.th.ing.test.dev` to `127.0.0.1` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually dead-simple with `dnsmasq`:

```
# install dnsmasq
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
# map anything ending in .dev to 127.0.0.1
echo address=/dev/127.0.0.1 | sudo tee /etc/dnsmasq.d/dev
# restart to make it read new config
sudo service dnsmasq restart
# verify it's working
host gsdf.gsd.fg.sdf.g.dev                               
# gsdf.gsd.fg.sdf.g.dev has address 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/hosts` (where you'd make an edit) doesn't allow wildcards. This leaves you with two choices:

1. Do without automatic subsdomains and just edit `/etc/hosts` each time you want a new one.
2. Push all your DNS through [a crazy DNS proxy](http://code.google.com/p/marlon-tools/source/browse/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py) ([per this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/265396/2619)) and change your network settings to the proxy. This will likely slow anything that makes a DNS query down a little but should let you do anything you like with domains.

I personally settle for just setting them myself. It only takes 10 seconds. But you might have different, stranger requirements.

---

Edit: Just had an idea. If you have a real domain (with real DNS hosting) you could set `*.local.mydomain.com` to point to `127.0.0.1` and that should work.

Comment: It looks like people are using bind9 to solve the problem? Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: I'd lump that in with the crazy DNS proxy - which is essentially what it would be, just harder to configure. I don't have any experience with BIND9 but there is [a help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto). You'll need to make sure you're using the `forwarders` setting to make sure DNS queries that your local DNS can't resolve are passed onto your ISP. But yes, certainly an option.

Comment: So from that help file, you want to mix the "Caching Server configuration" and "Primary Master Server configuration".